# Realm Database is always empty after restart

Tags: android, realm

I have a Realm based application where I save some data in. I also query that data afterwards on different screens by opening (and closing) different Realm instances via `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` and all works as expected. But, after each Restart of the app the realm database is empty.

I'm not using Realm's in memory feature and not `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()`.

My configuration looks like this:

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfig =
        new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context.getApplicationContext()).build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);
```

And then I use `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`.

Comment: You're probably calling `Realm.deleteAll()` somewhere.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem ... sorry!

Comment: I should consider playing the lottery at some point soon though, that was a rough guess :P

Comment: off-topic: Huh. I knew this name was familiar. You made [Mosby](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby)! Cool.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're calling commitTransaction properly?

If you call the same getDefaultInstance() even on multiple screens you get back the data since its in Realm, but you need to use commitTransaction() to write it to disk.

Comment: Read again: *I also query that data afterwards ... and all works as expected*

Comment: You CAN query a Realm database after you add data. That doesn't mean it is persisted on disk. Think of it like any other two-phase commit databases. You can change a lot of data AND then commit, so you spare a lot of transactional overhead etc. Realm works the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Realm clear shouldn't happen unless you either do:

1.) `deleteIfMigrationNeeded()` and then modify the schema

2.) use `inMemory()` realm and your process died at some point

3.) call `Realm.deleteAll()` somewhere in your code

4.) you manually delete the Realm file